# How to use the time of datePicker only after clicking at Save Button

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I am trying to use the hour and minutes of the date picker and add a notification with it. It is working now when the user immeadiatly chooses the hour and minutes from the DatePicker. My problem is that I only wanna create the notification when the user clicks at a Button Save, not when changing the value of the picker. How do I do that?

```
@objc func printMedHour(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let date = DateFormatter()
    date.timeStyle = .short

    let dateString = date.string(from: datePicker.date)

    let dateAsString = (dateString)//"1:15 PM"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    let dates = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    let Date24 = dateFormatter.string(from: dates!)

    //print(dateString)
    print(Date24)

    let hour = Date24.prefix(2)
    let minutes = Date24.suffix(2)

    print(hour)
    print(minutes)


    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Time to take your med"
    content.body = "Don't forget"

    var dateComponent = DateComponents()
    dateComponent.calendar = Calendar.current

    let hourString = (hour)
    let hourInt = Int(hourString)
    print(hourInt)

    let minuteString = (minutes)
    let minuteInt = Int(minuteString)
    print(minuteInt)

    //dateComponent.weekday = 7 //Saturday
    dateComponent.hour = (hourInt) as? Int //Hour
    dateComponent.minute = (minuteInt) as! Int //Minute

    //Trigger:
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error")

        }

    })







    self.reminderTextField.text = dateString
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

My Button is the following:

```
let saveButton: UIButton = {

   let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 40, green: 40, blue: 40)
    button.contentMode = .center
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 20)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveUserSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.isOpaque = true
    button.layer.opacity = 0.9
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddMedViewController.printMedHour(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    return button

}()
```

When adding the target to the date picker, the notification is not created.
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it's already fixed. I needed to use a different value for UIControl

Comment: If you have fixed the problem, then post your answer to the question and accept it so that other people can benefit from it as well :)

Comment: I changed the UIEventControl to all touch events and it is working now!

Comment: Not related to your question but don't hack around your issue. You should use Calendar method `Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: datePicker.date)` to get your date hour or minute components.